# Google Maps Api Key Custom Referrers Syntax

Tags: api, google-maps, url, google-maps-api-3, syntax

I'm trying to get this to work for my site, but I have a unique problem with syntax that I am not been able to find an answer for it yet.

For example:

www.mysite.dev.team.com (www.mysite.com is the site url)

What I need is basically the dev to be dynamic and open to any number after it so basically it could be dev7, dev8, dev9

How would I write this into the referrers api section in the Google Api Referrers list?

```
*.mysite.*.team.com/*
*.mysite*.com/*
```

I've tried multiple different combinations but nothing worked

Thanks

Comment: If the domain is `www.mysite.com`; subdomains would be `www.dev6.mysite.com` (`*.mysite.*.team.com` is a subdomain of the `team.com` domain). Most likely you want `*.mysite.com` for all subdomains of `mysite.com`.

Comment: @geocodezip Thank you!! *.team.com/* worked. Not sure why I didn't think of this before

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

```
*.team.com/*
```

fixed the problem